# How to mark a function as non-returning in Parasoft C++test?

Tags: c++, static-analysis, parasoft

We have a `die` function that outputs an error message and exits, e.g.:

```
void die(const char* msg) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", msg);
    exit(1);
}
```

We use [Parasoft C++test](http://www.parasoft.com/jsp/products/cpptest.jsp) to statically analyze our code, but it doesn't realize that `die` is a non-returning function. So when it sees code like:

```
void foo(Bar* bar) {
    if(!bar) {
        die("bar is NULL");
    }
    Bar bar2 = *bar;
}
```

It warns that `*bar` might be dereferencing a null pointer, even though `bar` being NULL would prevent that line from ever executing. Is there a way to mark `die` as non-returning in a way Parasoft would recognize?

---

**Edit**: I need something that works in both GCC and VS 2003, but I'm not above `#ifdef`ing my way around things if somebody has a solution that only works in VS

Comment: Could you just put a return after the call to die?  Would that fix it?

Comment: @Benjamin Sorry, I misread your comment originally. I guess that would work, but it's kind of inconvenient, particularly since `die()` will get used in functions that have non-trivial return types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. It turns out Parasoft has a built-in list of NRFs you can customize; they're called "terminating functions". You can edit them through the VS GUI or through the configuration file if you run Parasoft outside of VS

#### Through Visual Studio

- Open the `Test Configurations` dialog from the `C++test` menu
- Select your configuration
- Select the `Static` tab
- Select the `BugDetective Options` subtab
- Select the `Terminators` sub-subtab

  [Screenshot of the window http://so.mrozekma.com/parasoft1.png](http://so.mrozekma.com/parasoft1.png)
- Add a new entry with the non-returning function name

  [Screenshot of the entry http://so.mrozekma.com/parasoft2.png](http://so.mrozekma.com/parasoft2.png)

#### Through the configuration file

Add lines like the following:

```
com.parasoft.xtest.checker.flowanalysis.terminators.api0.methods=active\=true|name\=die|type\=*|paramsn\=*|defsInSubClasses\=true;
com.parasoft.xtest.checker.flowanalysis.terminators.apis=active\=true|name\=foo;
```

Answer (score 2):

In gcc, you should attribute the function with something like:

```
     die (const char *, ...) 
          __attribute__ ((format_arg (1)))
          __attribute__ ((noreturn))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Visual Studio 2005+, you can use [`__declspec(noreturn)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6ktzx3s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) like this:

```
__declspec(noreturn) void die(char const* msg){
  fprntf(stderr, "Error: %s\n"; msg);
  exit(1);
}
```

Maybe that helps Parasoft to recognize the function as non-returning.
**Edit:** GCC has [`__attribute__((noreturn))`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function%20Attributes) (first example).

Comment: I probably should've mentioned I need something that works in GCC and VS; I edited the question. I'll look into that though, if Parasoft picks up on it I can just `#ifdef` it out in GCC builds

Comment: Sadly, it looks like Parasoft doesn't notice `__declspec(noreturn)`; adding it didn't change the results

Comment: @Michael: Sorry then. :/ Maybe you can contact the parasoft support?